# How to get image url after taking screenshot in my Activity?

Tags: android

I want to get  **screenshot image** URL  that recently taken by **android device**, I need this for checking current image created by **my application**, not after **bitmap processing**

Comment: Use the media projection APIs to take the screenshot, and your `ImageReader` can then get the actual image. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/MediaProjection/andshooter).

Comment: Hey CommonsWare  thanks for the reply, I don't want use any API for taking the screenshot, I just need to know somebody takes the screenshot at any time even my application in foreground, background or not running .when  my application start again It should have information regarding last not scanned screenshot cursor

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Android SDK for you to find out if and when the user takes a screenshot. There is no guaranteed location where screenshots will be stored. There is no requirement for a device to have the ability for the user to take a screenshot.

So, take the screenshot yourself, using the media projection APIs. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/MediaProjection/andshooter).